# Ant Design Table expand Icon not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, antd

I am using [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/table) (v5) `Table` component in my React project. Inside the Table component, am using the `expandIcon` property belonging to the `expandable` prop, in order to expand only those rows which satisfy a certain condition. When I use the default expand icon (+), the icon is displayed only for the rows where I want to display it, i.e., it is displayed correctly.

[image]

However, when I use custom icons from [@ant-design/icons](https://ant.design/components/icon) for the expand icon, the icon is displayed for all rows, regardless of whether the row satisfies the condition or not.

[image]

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

To replicate the issue, go to https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-bird-nuzpr and replace the `index.js` code with the following -

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { PlusCircleTwoTone, MinusCircleTwoTone } from "@ant-design/icons";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Table } from "antd";

const columns = [
  { title: "Name", dataIndex: "name", key: "name" },
  { title: "Age", dataIndex: "age", key: "age" },
  { title: "Address", dataIndex: "address", key: "address" },
  {
    title: "Action",
    dataIndex: "",
    key: "x",
    render: () => <a href='https://www.google.com'>Delete</a>
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    key: 1,
    user_role: 3,
    name: "John Brown",
    age: 32,
    address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is John Brown, I am 32 years old, living in New York No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    user_role: 3,
    name: "Jim Green",
    age: 42,
    address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Jim Green, I am 42 years old, living in London No. 1 Lake Park."
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    user_role: 1,
    name: "Not Expandable",
    age: 29,
    address: "Jiangsu No. 1 Lake Park",
    description: "This not expandable"
  },
  {
    key: 4,
    user_role: 3,
    name: "Joe Black",
    age: 32,
    address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
    description:
      "My name is Joe Black, I am 32 years old, living in Sidney No. 1 Lake Park."
  }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table
    columns={columns}
    dataSource={data}
    expandable={{
      expandedRowRender: record => (
        <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>
      ),
      rowExpandable: (record) => {
        // console.log('rowExpandable: ', record)
        return record.user_role > 1 ? true : false
      },
      expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
        expanded ? (
          <MinusCircleTwoTone onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
        ) : (
          <PlusCircleTwoTone onClick={e => onExpand(record, e)} />
        )
    }}
  />,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I just need to change the `expandIcon` function like below, and it will work properly.

```
expandIcon: ({ expanded, onExpand, record }) =>
      record.user_role > 1 ? (
        expanded ? (
          <MinusCircleTwoTone onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)} />
        ) : (
          <PlusCircleTwoTone onClick={(e) => onExpand(record, e)} />
        )
      ) : null,
```

[image]